# Change sequence frame size Final Cut Express 4

Tags: video, final-cut-express

I have a sequence in Final Cut Express 4 that has 1080p video in it, but when I export it, it exports as 720p video, because the sequence settings are set to 720p video. How do I change the frame size?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think Menu -> Sequence -> Settings -> Load Sequence Preset..., then picking choosing a 1080p  preset might do what you want.  You'll probably have to delete and re-render anything you've pre-rendered.

You can set the default sequence preset for all new sequences with Easy Setup under the application menu.

Comment: Fantastic! Now how do I see this option? The only progressive option is 720p

Comment: Ah, sorry.  My mistake.  FCE4 only supports 1080i video.  FCP supports 1080p.  I usually take in 1080i50, export in AIC format, then deinterlace and output using the batch mode of MPEG Streamclip.